# Get dimensions of dynamically loaded DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to get the client dimensions of a dynamically embedded (with `XMLHttpRequest`) SVG:

```
var svg = document.getElementById("baseSVG");
```

I want `svg.clientWidth` etc. The SVG is scaled to fit a relative height in the client so the width is not known in advance. My code works in `chromium`. With `firefox` I see the SVG with that `id` in the DOM inspector, but `svg.clientWidth` is `0`.

The SVG is embedded in

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="slider">
            <ul>
                <li id="base">
                <object width="auto" height="100%" style="border:none" id="svgDiv">
                <!-- svg here -->
                </object>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a different method to know the client dimensions or a workaround?

Comment: Could be. The second best answer there seems to be a functioning workaround. However the original question is quite old ...

Comment: At least, did you try the answers ?

Comment: The problem (or question) there is a different, possibly related one. The accepted answer there does not work here. One of the answers works as workaround however.